# jQuery DOM Traversal - back then forward

Tags: jquery

need some help with DOM traversal for a trivia quiz. Structure is ..
There are a dynamic number of inner divs with a repeating question/answer structure ..

```
<div class="trivia_entry">
<div class="pad50">
<span>question</span>
..radio buttons...
<input type="button" class="quizbutt" value="NEXT" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="trivia_entry">
<div class="pad50">
<span class="pno">INCORRECT</span>
<p>answer description</p>
</div>
</div>
```

When the person clicks the NEXT button jQuery makes sure that they made a selection and then needs to change the class on the span of the next entry (the answer) to be "pyes" if their answer is correct. 
I can't seem to select the span though .. have tried (from within the button click handler)..

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().next('.trivia_entry span').removeClass('pno').addClass('pyes').html('CORRECT');
```

Any ideas truely appreciated :-)

Comment: the "$(this)" related to what?? and what exactly you want to select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of several `parent` methods you can use `closest` method:

```
$(this).closest('.trivia_entry')
       .next('.trivia_entry')
       .find('span')
       .removeClass('pno')
       .addClass('pyes')
       .html('CORRECT');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2JvHf

PS: You needed to use 2 parent methods instead of three, also `next` method doesn't work that way, you should remove the `span` from the selector and use `find` method instead.

Comment: Another nice thing about using `.closest` and `.find` is that your jQuery is less brittle in light of future tweaks to your HTML structure.

Comment: Thanks "undefined" :-) For the future how does .next work then? The .parent() selector went back to the containing 'trivia_entry' so I presumed .next would then work from there forwards.

Comment: @Andy You are welcome, `next` only checkes whether the next direct sibling element matched the specified selector or not, it doesn't select the descendant elements.

Comment: Thanks bud - that explains why you used a .find after .next instead of adding the descendant into the .next. Guess thats where I went wrong. Thanks for your help - works like a charm.